# Why does my Fn need to be Sync when spawned by Tokio?

Tags: rust, async-await, synchronization, send, rust-tokio

This is the code that raises a compiler error suggesting that `MyFn` should be restricted with a `Sync` bound:

```
use std::future::Future;

fn spawn<MyFn, Out>(func: MyFn)
where
    Out: Future + Send + 'static,
    MyFn: Fn() -> Out + Send + 'static,
{
    tokio::spawn(call_func(func));
}

async fn call_func<MyFn, Out>(func: MyFn)
where
    MyFn: Fn() -> Out,
    Out: Future,
{
    func().await;
    func().await;
}
```

[Link to the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a204e9f6a756072731442f81745c2e1a).

This raises the following error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:8:18
    |
8   |     tokio::spawn(call_func(func));
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `call_func` is not `Send`
    |
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:16:11
    |
16  |     func().await;
    |     ----  ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `func` maybe used later
    |     |
    |     has type `&MyFn` which is not `Send`
note: `func` is later dropped here
   --> src/main.rs:16:17
    |
16  |     func().await;
    |                 ^
help: consider moving this into a `let` binding to create a shorter lived borrow
   --> src/main.rs:16:5
    |
16  |     func().await;
    |     ^^^^^^
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.21.2/src/task/spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
help: consider dereferencing here
    |
8   |     tokio::spawn(*call_func(func));
    |                  +
help: consider further restricting this bound
    |
6   |     MyFn: Fn() -> Out + Send + 'static + std::marker::Sync,
    |                                        +++++++++++++++++++

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Why exaclty does `MyFn` need to be restricted using the `Sync` bound, when all that [tokio::spawn](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) requires is the following?

```
pub fn spawn<T>(future: T) -> JoinHandle<T::Output>ⓘ
where
    T: Future + Send + 'static,
    T::Output: Send + 'static,
```

Comment: Probably because you're using the multi-threaded tokio executor.  In that scenario, you can't guarantee a given task runs in the same thread, so it needs to be safe to share.  The document you link calls that out specifically with its link to Runtime configuration.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley if you are referring to the `tokio::spawn` docs it says that the "spawned task may execute on the current thread, or it may be sent to a different thread to be executed" not shared. Also, I can't see any `Sync` requirement in [its implementation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/src/tokio/task/spawn.rs.html).

Comment: `&MyFn` (note the reference) must be `Send`, which implies that `MyFn` (no reference) must be `Sync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```rust
async fn call_func<MyFn, Out>(func: MyFn)
where
    MyFn: Fn() -> Out,
    Out: Future,
{
    func().await;
    func().await;
}
```

you are calling `func` twice. The way this is possible — why it doesn't violate Rust's move semantics even though `MyFn` does not have a `Copy` bound — is that `func` is being called *by `&` reference*, since it is a `Fn` and the definition of `Fn` is that you can call a function if you have `&` to it. Then, since there is an `await` in the middle, this code might move between threads. So, references to the value `func` is being used from two different threads, so `&MyFn: Send` is required, so `MyFn: Sync` is required.

Here's one trick to solve the problem: declare the function as `FnMut` instead of `Fn`. This means that a `&mut` reference is understood to be required to call the function, and since `&mut` references are unique they don't require `Send` of their referent. These changes compile successfully:

```rust
fn spawn<MyFn, Out>(func: MyFn)
where
    Out: Future + Send + 'static,
    MyFn: FnMut() -> Out + Send + 'static,
{
    tokio::spawn(call_func(func));
}

async fn call_func<MyFn, Out>(mut func: MyFn)
where
    MyFn: FnMut() -> Out,
    Out: Future,
{
    func().await;
    func().await;
}
```

In principle, the compiler could observe that the internal `&MyFn` never needs to move between threads, and do the equivalent of my `FnMut` rewrite internally (every `Fn` is also a `FnMut`), but evidently it doesn't.